# One time use Elytra in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a survival server for me and friends with some additions. In the world, you spawn on a floating island in a normal world. On the island you have to automatically get an elytra that is stuck to the chest and can't be taken off. When trying to take the elytra off, the elytra has  to disappear. Beneath the floating island will be a little island in a lake that will have a button the player will need to press to get teleported to the top of the island. When that button is pressed, the elytra should also be put onto the player.

Now to the elytras attributes.

You can only use the elytra once. Meaning that after you activate it(fly), it will disappear as soon as you land (deactivate it).

Is this possible to make?

The code I already got looks like this:

```
/give @p minecraft:elytra{CustomModelData:0,display:{Name:'[{"text":"OneTimeUse Elytra","italic":true,"color":"light_purple","bold":true}]',Lore:['[{"text":"This magical elytra can only be used once. After you land, it will disappear.","color":"aqua"}]']},Enchantments:[{}]} 1
```

I would love to know if this is possible just by using vanilla or if not what I have to do to make it possible.

I'm playing in Minecraft version 1.16.4/vanilla

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use data packs?  I have a idea that would probably require a data pack.  I have an idea that would work without a data pack too, but I will need to test these ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe what you have asked specifically is possible, *but* you can set up a system to clear the elytra of any players within a certain distance. Let’s say 0, 10, 0 is our landing zone:

```
/clear @a[x=0,y=10,z=0,distance=..4] elytra
```

Then place that command block anywhere where it will be loaded in.

Comment: okay, thank you, is it also possible to delete it after like a time period like 1 minute?

Comment: @JovadaPlayz could you clarify, I don’t exactly understand what your asking

Comment: Sorry, I mean I know it is possible for the player to collect the elytra by pressing a button which is connected to a command block which has a command in it that puts the elytra on the persons chest and it will have the curse of binding on it and in my test world, I put a redstone clock connected to it that takes a minute to run out and then it deletes the elytra off the person again. But the things I need and was wondering if they would work are: Can I display the time somewhere on the players screen, Can I only delete the elytra of a specific player, and IS there a time delay option?

Comment: @JovadaPlayz I would suggest looking into tags for keeping track of people and scoreboards or xp for a timer display